# Что такое адаптер?

Tags: c++

Читая книгу по STL я столкнулся с термином **адаптер** и сразу полез в поисковик что бы осветить этот вопрос и ни чего полезного не нашел.

В книге говорится что это реализация одного типа контейнера другим типом контейнера. В общем понятного мало.

Расскажите своими словами что такое **адаптер** в STL.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

<sup>Хочу начать с небольшого предисловия: такого понятия как STL в C++ не существует, есть стандартная библиотека и этого термина стоит придерживаться. Раньше термин STL использовали для обозначения стандартной библиотеки, но сейчас это считается моветоном.</sup>

Что же такое адаптер? Это, по существу, устоявшийся паттерн, который приходит к нам из реального мира. Мы берём одну сущность и адаптируем её к новым условиям через другую сущность. Безусловно, понятнее не стало.

Что имеется в виду в книге? Вероятно там разговор идёт о стеке и прочих контейнерах-адапторах. Почему они адапторы? Потому что внутри себя используют полноценный контейнеры, такие как `std::vector` и `std::deque`, и *адаптируют их интерфейс под другой интерфейс*. К примеру, `std::vector` имеет методы `push_back`, `insert` и `pop_back`, но такие операции для стека не нужны, стеку нужны 3 операции(основные) `top`, `pop` и `push`. Но все эти операции реализованы через соответсвующие операции `std::vector`, который скрывается в недрах `std::stack`. Поэтому `stack` не выделяют как самостоятельный контейнер — он есть адаптер для `std::vector`.

Другими словами: адаптер это понятие, которое выходит далеко за рамки стандартной библиотеки C++ и, в целом, им можно пренебречь изучая C++, т.к. является ли контейнер адаптером или нет не является ключевой частью. Это интересно знать, но не более того.

Comment: вот спасибо вам. очень помогли. а я уже подумал что адаптер это как раз вектор в стеке так называется, а тут как раз наоборот это контейнер использующий вспомогательный контейнер.

Comment: @perfect, не пытайтесь сузить понимание только этими контейнерами, это Вас только больше запутает. К примеру, если у Вас есть печь, с треугольным «входом» и круглая кострюля, которая меньше этого входа. Так вот, чтобы эффективнее нагреть кастрюлю Вы можете сделать треугольный **адаптер**. Который скроет в себе круглую кастрюлю и будет как раз под «интерфейс» нашей печи

Comment: все правильно я стек и вектор просто в пример привел. к тому же в сети теперь появиться ответ на этот вопрос

Answer (score 8):

Адаптировать - это значит приспосабливать. То есть приспосабливать существующую сущность, контейнер, итератор и т.д., , в новом контексте или для частной задачи.

Например, стандартный контейнер двусвязный список `std::list` имеет такие методы, как `push_back`, `push_front`, `pop_back`, `pop_front`, `front,` `back`.

Используя лишь подмножество методов, предоставляемых контейнером `std::list`, можно смоделировать поведение такой структуры данных, как стек.

В структуре данных стек данные организованы по принципу: последний вошел в стек - первый вышел из стека, то есть `LIFO` (last in, first out).

Обычно методы контейнера стек получают названия `push`, `pop`, `top`, как, например, в C++, или `Push`, `Pop`, `Peek`, как, например, в C# или другие названия. Но независимо от присвоенных названий методов их поведение семантически одно и то же.

Чтобы построить в C++ из списка стек, достаточно использовать методы либо `push_front`, `pop_front`, `front`, либо `push_back`, `pop_back`, `back` соответственно для методов стека `push`, `pop`, `top`.

Для этого просто в реализации данных методов стека следует вызывать соответствующие методы контейнера `std::list`.

Например, метод стека `pop` может быть реализован как вызов соответствующего метода контейнера `std::list`, который в примерах обозначен именем `c` от английского слова `container`:

```
void pop() { c.pop_back(); }
```

или

```
void pop() { c.pop_front(); }
```

Поэтому нет необходимости определять управление данными контейнера стек. Всю работу по управлению данными возьмет на себя контейнер `std::list`. Просто его методы, фактически, переименованы для **адаптации** к названиям методов контейнера стек.

Поэтому стек реализован не с нуля, а он просто является адаптацией класса `std::list` под логику работы стека, то есть стек - это **адаптер контейнера**.

Чтобы было возможно как можно больше последовательных контейнеров адаптировать под стек, было принято соглашение ограничиться методами последовательных контейнеров `push_back`, `pop_back`, и `back`, так как эти методы более широко распространены среди последовательных контейнеров. Например, контейнер `std::vector` не имеет методов `push_front` и `pop_front`, поэтому его нельзя было использовать для моделирования методов стека, используя именно эти методы последовательных контейнеров.

Однако стандартный последовательный контейнер `std::forward_list`, который был введен в стандарт C++ позже остальных стандартных последовательных контейнеров, не имеет методов `push_back`, `pop_back` и `back`. Поэтому адаптер контейнеров `std::stack` не может адаптировать этот контейнер для реализации стека.

Тем не менее я уже предложил Комитетам по стандартизации C++ включить специализацию класса `std::stack` для контейнера `std::forward_list`.
Это не представляет принципиальных трудностей сделать.

Существует лишь одно несоответствии: класс `std::forward_list` не имеет метода `size`, который присутствует в адаптере контейнеров `std::stack`. С моей точки зрения это не принципиально.

Аналогичный подход используется для адаптеров итераторов. Примером такого адаптера итераторов является `std::reverse_iterator`. Он адаптирует оператор `operator --` других итераторов таким образом, что когда используется оператор `operator ++`, то на самом деле вызывается оператор `operator --`. Это позволяет перебирать элементы контейнера или последовательности в обратном порядке, не меняя код, который основывается на применении оператора `operator ++` .

Например, если у вас имеется функция, которая выводит в поток элементы некоторого контейнера посредством передачи в функцию диапазона элементов с помощью двух итератор, как, например

```
template <class ForwardIterator>
std::ostream & display( ForwardIterator first, 
                        ForwardIterator last,
                        std::ostream &os = std::cout )
{
    for ( ; first != last; ++first )
    {
        os << *first << ' ';
    }

    return os;
}
```

То, передавая реверсивные итераторы, вы могли бы, например, выводить элементы массива целых чисел в обратном порядке:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

template <class ForwardIterator>
std::ostream & display( ForwardIterator first, 
                        ForwardIterator last,
                        std::ostream &os = std::cout )
{
    for ( ; first != last; ++first )
    {    
        os << *first << ' ';
    }

    return os;
}

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 10;
    int a[N] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    display( a, a + N ) << std::endl;
    display( std::reverse_iterator<int *>( a + N ), std::reverse_iterator<int *>( a ) ) << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
```

В данной программе адаптер итераторов `std::reverse_iterator` **адаптирует** указатели типа `int *` для операций с ними в обратном порядке следования элементов массива. Он использует те методы указателей, которые уже определены и существуют для указателей.

Для разнообразия в качестве еще одного примера адаптера итераторов можете познакомиться с предложенным мной адаптером итераторов `iterator_pair`, который я описал в своей статье в журнале [ACCU Overload #126](http://accu.org/var/uploads/journals/Overload126.pdf) либо по ссылкам, приведенной на моей персональной странице [здесь](http://cpp.forum24.ru/?1-3-0-00000065-000-0-0-1429900705) и [здесь](http://cpp.forum24.ru/?1-10-0-00000000-000-0-0-1428232189)